# Custom field to store managed object

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is it possible for a custom field to store a managed object as value ? If yes, any advices on how it can be achieved ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "managed object"?  An instance of a C# class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about a custom field that can do that, I've never really heard of anything like that being done.

That being said, if you can make your class serializable, you might be able to serialize it to JSON and store it in a regular SharePoint Note field.